# How to change access to view for users in database for ScadaLTS

Tags: scada, scadalts

- In version 0.0.7.4 ScadaLTS
- Linux (ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
- Mysql (5.7.10)

I have set role with restrictions for some about 10 users.

- I added new view
- I want to change the restriction from old view for users to new view.

From UI I can't do it so I will want to change this in the database.

Answer (score 0):

We can check user access to the view

```
SELECT * FROM mangoViewUsers WHERE mangoViewId = (oldID);
```

We can check user access to the view

```
UPDATE mangoViewUsers SET mangoViewId = (newID) WHERE mangoViewId = (oldID)
```

And again we check user access to the view

```
SELECT * FROM mangoViewUsers where mangoViewId = (newID);
```

New view should be visible to users with restriction.